# ASPX missingfieldexception error

Tags: asp.net

I have just updated my company website and it looked fine at first. Then a few seconds after loading, I encounter this error:

```
System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: xxx.include.NaviBar.ASPnetMenu1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple questions:
1.) Are you on a shared server that is perhaps running in a Medium Trust environment

2.) Is this a custom site or a framework, like dotnetnuke?

The missingfieldexception usually comes up when you're using reflection and are trying to access a property or method that doesn't exist. Medium Trust environments sometimes won't allow the reflection classes to be called, or the access to the functionality is limited.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingfieldexception.aspx

Comment: im not so sure of the server's security and setting. but it was okay a whie ago, then it showed the error like few seconds later.
my update was some html codes, so it shldnt be server environment issues, i presume.

Comment: Have you tried recycling the application pool or restarting the Web Server services ?